# Hackerrank Sparse Arrays in Swift

Tags: programming-challenge, swift

I solved this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sparse-arrays) and was looking for feedback on my code. More efficient, cleaner, more verbose variable names, anything helps.

> There are N strings. Each string's length is no more than 20  characters. There are also Q  queries. For each query, you are given a string, and you need to find out how many times this string occurred previously.

```
import Foundation

func readIntegers() -> Int {
    return Int(readLine()!)!
}

func sparseArrays() {
    let numOfStrings = readIntegers()
    var arrayOfStrings = [String]()
    for _ in 0..<numOfStrings {
        let string = readLine()!
        arrayOfStrings.append(string)
    }
    let numOfQueries = readIntegers()
    for _ in 0..<numOfQueries {
        let singleString = readLine()!
        let arrayOfSingleString = arrayOfStrings.filter {$0 == singleString}
        print(arrayOfSingleString.count)
    }
}

sparseArrays()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> func readIntegers() -> Int {
>     return Int(readLine()!)!
> }
> ```

Now this is confusing! A function called  `readIntegers` which returns
a *single* integer? `readInteger()` or `readInt()` would be an
appropriate name.

The forced unwrapping is acceptable because the input comes from a
programming challenge with well-defined input. However, finding 
errors in your code is easier if you check the optionals explicitly
and print an descriptive error message if the input does not
match the expectations.

And with a short description (using the "markdown format" which is
recognized by the Xcode "Quick Help inspector") it
becomes a reusable function for this and future programming
challenges:

```
/// Returns an integer read from one line of standard input.
func readInteger() -> Int {
    guard let line = readLine() else {
        fatalError("Unexpected end of input")
    }
    guard let i = Int(line) else {
        fatalError("Invalid integer in input")
    }
    return i
}
```

The same for reading a single string:

```
/// Returns a string read from one line of standard input.
func readString() -> String {
    guard let line = readLine() else {
        fatalError("Unexpected end of input")
    }
    return line
}
```

I am (usually) not a fan of adding type information to a variable
name, `arrayOfStrings` should just be named `strings` (as in the
description of the challenge).

Instead of starting with an empty array and adding elements one
can create the array with `map()`. This also allows us to declare the array as a *constant:*

```
let numOfStrings = readInteger()
let strings = (0..<numOfStrings).map {
    _ in readString()
}
```

`singleString` is better named `query`, and `arrayOfSingleString`
is the array with all strings matching the query:

```
let numOfQueries = readInteger()
for _ in 0..<numOfQueries {
    let query = readString()
    let matchingStrings = strings.filter { $0 == query }
    print(matchingStrings.count)
}
```

We are only interesting in the *count* of matching elements.
To improve the performance, determine the count without creating
an intermediate array:

```
    let matchingCount = strings.reduce(0) { (accum, str) in
        accum + (str == query ? 1 : 0)
    }
    print(matchingCount)
```

Another speed-up could be achieved by

- Sorting the given strings, this needs to be done only once.
- Use binary search to find a query string in the array.
- If the string is found, traverse forward and backward through
  the array to determine how many strings are equal to the query string.

Comment: I didn't know we could use map over a range, i thought it was only on arrays. Awesome!